# HTML Div Creating Block Link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am a very beginner web developer. Very new to it, and decided it was time I actually made some headway.

Anyway, I'm having an issue with an apparent block link, which is everywhere below the header of my site. As you can see from this screenshot: http://puu.sh/YLDH it shouldn't be linking to  anything where my cursor currently is.

My HTML code can be found here, along with my CSS (It's not long): http://pastie.org/4587834

If anyone could help, that would be awesome.

Thanks so much!

Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close `<a>` tags.

Try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Tom Richardson</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="d6d6d6">
      <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <div id="navbarlinks">
                  <ul id="navlist">
                  <li><a href="About.html"><img src="images/About.png" alt="About" width="108" height="48" /></a></li>
                  <li><a href="Contact.html"><img src="images/Contact%20Me.png" alt="Contact%20Me" width="202" height="48" /></a></li>
                  <li><a href="JBN.html"><img src="images/JBN.png" alt="JBN" width="65" height="48" /></a></li>
                  <li><a href="Blog.html"><img src="images/Blog.png" alt="Blog" width="83" height="48" /></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contactform">


    </div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!! Knew it would be something silly like that!